# How to convert UTC date of specific timezone to UTC +0 (default Greenwich)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to insert an item to the DB in a specific date based on the client's timezone. So if client desired in today on 20:00, and his timezone is +3, I want that node and mongodb will set the date to be on today on 17:00. I hope that is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is recommended to save all timestamps in database in UTC only, along with it you can save extra field timezone/offset value in each document. Check - 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/

But if you want to save in local timezone, you need to do conversion at application level before inserting in database.